# Conversion form string "PatientName" to type "Integer" is not valid error in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, runtime-error

Im working on my application and suddenly i encounter an error that says "Conversion form string "PatientName" to type "Integer" is not valid"
i can't really find where im wrong at, i don't really get this error, im new in vb.net, help me figure it out please
here's my code:

```
 Private Sub RsdcAddPage_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim READER As SQLiteDataReader
    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim sql As String
        sql = "SELECT * FROM patienttbl"
        cmd = New SQLiteCommand(sql, con)
        READER = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While READER.Read
            Dim sName = READER.GetString("PatientName")
            namecb.Items.Add(sName)

        End While
        con.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally


    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: GetString needs index `reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("PatientName"))` https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader~GetString(Int32).html Also, to avoid similar errors use Option Strict https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/4022/option-strict/14043/how-to-switch-it-on#t=201701300421042168261

Comment: Thank God, You are a life Saver